# get selectbox selected value by name tag jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectbox

I have a form like this

```
<label>Select country</label>  
    <select name="country">
        <option value="IND" selected="selected">India</option>
        <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
        <option value="US">United states</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

I want to get the value of selected country using jquery.

This is my code in jquery document block: My jquery version: jquery-1.10.1.js

```
alert($('select[name="country"]').find(":selected").val());
alert($('select[name="country"] option:selected').val());
```

I dont like to call the selector by ID or class. Thanks in advance.

I couldn't write onChange for the country select-box. I need to execute ajax request on blur of the date input field(followup_date).

```
$('#followup_date').change(function(e) {

        if($(this).val()!='')
        {
            //$('.tmslot').not(this).attr('checked', false);        
            var slot = $(this).val();
            var country_id = $('select[name="country"] option:selected').val();
```

My problem is I am getting **undefined** for **country_id**.

Comment: you need this $('select[name="country"]').val();

Comment: `alert($('select[name="country"]').val());` should be fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sof2pjbs/2/

Comment: This works for me `$('select[name="country"]').find(":selected").val();`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `.val()` on `select` element not on selected `option`:

```js
$('select[name="country"]').on('change', function(){    
    alert($(this).val());    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="country">
        <option value="IND" selected="selected">India</option>
        <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
        <option value="US">United states</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Tim, thanks a lot for your time. But, I couldn't write onChange for the select-box. I need to execute ajax request on blur of the input field.

Comment: @chandoo Always welcome! Please feel free to mark my answer as accepted:) `on('cahnge')` here is just for example to demonstrate the main idea - use `$('select[name="country"]').val()` for getting the value of `select` element.

Answer (score 7):

As per docs,

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. In the case of select elements, it returns null when no option is selected and an array containing the value of each selected option when there is at least one and it is possible to select more because the multiple attribute is present.

You need to simply use `.val()` with select elements jquery object to get selected option value:

```
$('select[name="country"]').val()
```

Comment: @KishoreKumar: can you reproduce the issue in fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to get the option:

> alert($('select[name=country]').find(':selected').text());

Comment: this would give you the text i.e. Malaysia instead of value MY

Answer (score 2):

You may need this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fe47xeg4/)

```
alert($('select[name="country"]').val());
$('select[name="country"]').change(function(){    
    alert($(this).val());    
});
```